# How to get the exact number of characters in a MS Word document using IronPython

Tags: ironpython

I'm using the `Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces` object of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to get the total number of characters in a Word document. However, I got different results in term of total characters from what is declared inside the Word application, when it is open and checked manually.

Here is my code:

```python
import clr
import sys

clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word as Word

def count_characters(docfile):
    word_application = Word.ApplicationClass()
    word_application.visible = False
    document = word_application.Documents.Open(docfile)
    ranges = document.Content
    ranges.Select()
    total_characters = ranges.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces)
    document.Close()
    word_application.Quit()
    return total_characters


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        docfile = sys.argv[1]
        number = count_characters(docfile)
        print(number)
```

Comment: Have you tested with a document with a small, known count? For example "abc " vs. "abc \r\n" and see how many characters it counts the newline as? I wonder if that could account for the difference.